# Low performance in Mysql 5.6.12

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the table with about 30 columns, and then I add one column to that table. In mysql 5.6.12 this operation takes about 0.7 seconds, when in mysql 5.0.51 it takes more more smaller.

The whole database takes about 2.7 Mb. We ues InnoDb. All settings are default.

Could anyone tell me why in mysql 5.6.12 altering queries are executed so slowly? Is there any tweak related to this? Maybe is there any known bug related to this issue?

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If adding a column to a table is a performance critical issue on your application, something is very wrong in the design... Also, MySQL has a couple of DB engines. Which one are you using? Are they the same?

Comment: such operations is not problem in mysql 5.0.51.. Why?

Comment: I think even 7 seconds would be fine. (Ok, that is an exaggeration, that would be the sign of something bad considering data sizes this small). How often do you need to add a column to a table?

Comment: Really not often - only when we do release. But still I'm hoping that I've missed something in mysql configuration that could fix this issue...

Comment: Is there any other measurable impact on performance other than this? (Sorry Somehow I missed the notion of InnoDB in the question). Are the two DBS on the same machine?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what youa re trying to achieve? There are different ways to alter tables, therefore it might be possible to give you a faster solution. And there should be no way why such an operation on a small db should take that long.

Comment: @Flo Doe, I just alter any table - it isn't depend on any special characteristics of table or query. Such as I've described in the head of question - I have table with 30 columns and want to add one column.

Comment: @ppeterka DBS are reside on different machines. I have performance problems only with altering tables.

Comment: @Dedyshka You first have to go through design as it seems that your database design is wrong. Post table creation and alter statements. That might help.

Comment: Compare what is comparable. Install your older version of MySQL on the new server, with the same settings. Then time how long it takes to alter the table on v5.0 and v5.6. I am ready to bet the problem is hardware-related.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following points

- How many rows are there in table ?
- Is there any default assignment being done when a new column is getting added ?
- Check space available in `data` directory of mysql-5.6 and compare it to mysql-5.5 installation 'data' directory.
- Check steps which were followed to migrate/upgrade from mysql-5.5 to mysql-5.6 ? May be something was wrong there.